# A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'. > Could not find method android() for arguments

Tags: build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I tried cloaning a git repo and I tried to update the sdk version becasue flutter was giving me null saftey error. Now I have the error I have been battling with

error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\card\android\build.gradle' line: 25
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments [build_drz5x338esx0lx7zm5m5pv7fx$_run_closure2$_closure6@58ec4faa] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 54s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried bumping complidedsdk 31.

here is the code

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {

    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 31 // <-- This
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.app"
            targetSdkVersion 31 // <-- and this too
            // ...
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```